# Is automatic building while push a change to git repository (not git hub only a remote networked computer) is possible with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to know if automatic building while push a change to repository (not git hub only a remote networked computer) is possible through jenkins.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Jenkins can periodically check the repo for changes, for example.

Comment: I'm not a Jenkins expert, so I don't know the details.  I'd recommend going to the Jenkins documentation, which is pretty reasonable.  http://jenkins-ci.org